# Bounds on inverse elements of Hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an  $N$ by $N$ Hermitian matrix with elements $a_{ij}$. What will be the bound on the elements $b_{ij}$ where $B=A^{-1}$?
If $A$ is a diagonal matrix, solution is trivial. Also for tri-diagonal matrix, bounds exists.

Comment: For tridiagonal matrices, bounds on inverse elements exist. Want to know about Hermitian matrices.

Comment: if you are more specific, you can (possibly) get more help...

Answer (score 6):

If H is a Hermitian matrix whose eigenvalues all have absolute value $\ge r$, then the matrix elements of $H^{-1}$ are bounded by $1/r$.

Comment: Can you provide a reference?

Comment: Diagonalize $H = U^* D U$ where $U$ is unitary, $D$ is diagonal and * is Hermitian conjugate.  Moreover, $D = R |D|$ where $R$ is diagonal with diagonal elements $\pm 1$ (and thus unitary).  Then for any unit column vectors $u$ and $v$, $u^* H^{-1} v = (R U u)^* |D|^{-1} (U v)$ where $RUu$ and $Uv$ are unit vectors.  Now use Cauchy-Schwarz for the inner product
$(x,y) \to x^* |D|^{-1} y$, and $x^* |D|^{-1} x \le (1/r) x^* x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't expect such a succinct proof sketch.